# Prevent object creation if some conditions are violated

Tags: matlab, object, oop, constructor, conditional-statements

In a script I want to create an object of a class only if all the constructor inputs meet some conditions. All the checks are embedded in the constructor itself. Problem is when:

```
myObj = myClass(input1,input2,...);
```

is triggered in the script. The object, even when an input doesn't meet the relative condition, is still created eventually with all empty properties.

Inserting the following code within the constructor:

```
if nargout == 0
   clear obj;
end
```

prevents the creation of the object, but only when the output is assigned to the `ans` variable. Otherwise, I get an error.

Is there a way to obtain something like that without adding some code directly into the script (like using `try`)?

Comment: It's not clear what your expected behaviour would be - to error? To make some sort of empty placeholder where the object would otherwise be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the constructor throws an error, no object will be created. Use [`error`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html). You can put a `try`/`catch` block around the constructor call if you like.

There is no way AFAIK to have the constructor return normally but produce no object. What would be assigned to its output?

Comment: yes as I thought. Thank you so much for your help and for your time!